# Cisco ASA Possible arp issue?

Tags: cisco, arp

I've changed our Watchguard XTM firewall for Cisco ASA 5508-x, all seems to be working but do have one problem though... The nat / pat connections from the outside stop working.

We have a single external IP address, and so use effectively port forwarding to open firewall to the servers. The connections are fine from inside, but not from the internet.

If I do a "clear arp" on the firewall, the connections start working again for a while...

I disabled the secondary firewall.

On some servers, there were two nic's connected without any teaming software, so I've removed the second cable.

I've rebooted the servers but still get the issue...

Any thoughts?

Here's an example of the nat config for a connection to a servers port 80 using port 90 on the outside

object network Server1_90
 host 192.168.1.66

access-list OUTSIDE extended permit tcp any object Server1_90 eq www

object network Server1_90
 nat (inside,EXT_PUB_INT) static interface service tcp www 90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate IP issue to me. Is outbound traffic working fine when your servers are not reachable from the Internet?

Comment: There are some devices that work on out bound traffic and some that do not. It's a massive /17 subnet completely flat too that I've inherited...

Comment: Found someone had put a wireless access point on the network somewhere...

Comment: Did the AP act as a DHCP server? If yes, you may want to look at DHCP snooping, which may be enabled on your switches to block DHCP replies from untrusted ports.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using interface MNAT, it may be proxy arp issue..
Can you share the output of command below:

```
show running-config sysopt
```

Comment: This is the only command in that section

`sysopt connection timewait`

Comment: Sysopt proxy arp is enabled by default and those commands will not be shown in running-config. Can you try this command.. show running-config all | I sysopt

Comment: Also if possible, check for duplicate ARP for single MAC..

Comment: I've looked at the arp table and there are no duplicates.

It's exhibitting the issue at the moment too.

Comment: no sysopt traffic detailed-statistics
sysopt connection timewait
sysopt connection tcpmss 1380
sysopt connection tcpmss minimum 0
sysopt connection permit-vpn
sysopt connection reclassify-vpn
no sysopt connection preserve-vpn-flows
no sysopt radius ignore-secret
no sysopt noproxyarp EXT_PUB_INT
no sysopt noproxyarp DMZ_INT
no sysopt noproxyarp inside
no sysopt noproxyarp PUB_DMZ_INT
no sysopt noproxyarp PUB_OSZ_INT
no sysopt noproxyarp PUB_ISZ_INT
no sysopt noproxyarp CUS_DMZ_INT
no sysopt noproxyarp management

Comment: Are you able too see untranslate hits increasing while you facing issue? We can see that using : show nat command... Also check whether you are getting any embryonic connection at the time of issue using show conn state tcp_embryonic.. try debug arp.. please share you IOS version too...

Comment: IOS Version is  9.5(1) - Upgraded to the latest due to a bug in the IOS with VPNs.

Comment: If you could, share me the above requested command results.. Proxy ARP is enabled on the external interface. Though proxy ARP will not participate for ARP respond for interface IP, we saw misbehaviour in our ASA IOS version 9.1(6)4.. Can you try disabling proxy ARP in the NAT statement by this command : sysopt noproxyarp EXT_PUB_INT ( If you disable proxy arp, please make sure that you enable routing for NAT IP's in the same range of ext interface IP towards firewall from outside connected device..)

Comment: Here's the tcp_embryonic:
354 in use, 1213 most used

TCP EXT_PUB_INT  192.168.180.109:53874 inside  192.168.1.6:16773, idle 0:00:00, bytes 0, flags SaAB
TCP EXT_PUB_INT  192.168.180.106:53345 inside  192.168.1.6:16773, idle 0:00:12, bytes 0, flags SaAB
TCP EXT_PUB_INT  86.150.162.116:51893 inside  192.168.1.8:443, idle 0:00:04, bytes 0, flags SxaAB
TCP EXT_PUB_INT  82.132.245.57:44939 inside  192.168.1.8:443, idle 0:00:01, bytes 0, flags SxaAB
TCP EXT_PUB_INT  82.132.219.122:10000 inside  192.168.1.8:443, idle 0:00:13, bytes 0, flags SxaAB

Comment: Debug arp: arp-in: request at inside from 192.168.1.8 842b.2b0b.cdb7 for 192.168.8.40 0000.0000.0000 having smac 842b.2b0b.cdb7 dmac ffff.ffff.ffff
arp-set: added arp inside 192.168.1.8 842b.2b0b.cdb7 and updating NPs at 178668520
arp-in: request at inside from 192.168.8.200 1803.7351.9cf0 for 192.168.1.25 0000.0000.0000 having smac 1803.7351.9cf0 dmac ffff.ffff.ffff
arp-set: added arp inside 192.168.8.200 1803.7351.9cf0 and updating NPs at 178668590
arp-send: arp request built from 192.168.1.1 5c83.8fce.1c9c for 192.168.0.254 at 178669010

Comment: Obviously these have been truncated do to the length of the text

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont see any logs with specific to your server 192.168.1.66 in the logs you provided... Did you try disabling proxy arp using sysopt noproxyarp EXT_PUB_INT and sysopt noprpxyarp inside commands?? Also share the device details that is connected to inside and EXT interface...

Comment: Here's the debug arp with 192.168.1.66 in it
arp-in: request at inside from 192.168.1.66 782b.cb59.97d6 for 192.168.1.250 0000.0000.0000 having smac 782b.cb59.97d6 dmac ffff.ffff.ffff
arp-set: added arp inside 192.168.1.66 782b.cb59.97d6 and updating NPs at 197055430

Comment: This is the 
TCP EXT_PUB_INT  104.145.231.104:34920 inside  192.168.1.66:80, idle 0:00:01, bytes 0, flags SxaAB
TCP EXT_PUB_INT  92.232.99.125:51139 inside  192.168.1.66:80, idle 0:00:04, bytes 0, flags SxaAB
TCP EXT_PUB_INT  92.232.99.125:51137 inside  192.168.1.66:80, idle 0:00:04, bytes 0, flags SxaAB
TCP EXT_PUB_INT  104.145.234.95:60276 inside  192.168.1.66:80, idle 0:00:14, bytes 0, flags SxaAB

Comment: The inside interface has a Netgear GS248t connected with every port untagged on VLAN1. Interestingly non of this happened with the Watchguard firewall...

Comment: I've run sysopt noproxyarp EXT_PUB_INT and on inside. I've cleared the arp again and will see what happens

Comment: Still getting the same issue. I've looked on the server, and did an arp -a. The mac address for 192.168.1.1 is showing as the switch... I can't remember if that's correct or not, but I would have thought that it should be the firewall?

Comment: Please check the following,

1. At the time of issue are able to ping that server from firewall? 

2. Check for packet tracer result whether you are getting any drop

3. Enable capture in Ext and inside interface to see whether the packets reaching firewall is getting into inside network and the return packet is reaching the firewall

4. Check for wireshark logs at the server to see whether the packets are reaching server after crossing the firewall and response packets are sent back from server.

5. Share me network flow with in between device details. If things are clear, raise Cisco case.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue...

Someone had put a wireless access point somewhere with the same IP address as the inside of the firewall